# Why do I get an error message on Wordpress blog posts (only) on my local environment (and on the original server I don't)

Tags: php, database, wordpress, .htaccess, wamp

I copied all my WP files from the server to my local WAMP as a dev-environment. 
Everything works smoothly except when viewing a blog post.

I get a good output of all the titles/categories/post-content/ect' - But with a strange output before the blogs content:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JTKJ5.png
[image: <code>enter image description here</code>]

content.php Line 68 is this part in the code: `__(  ),`

One line after "the_content" function:

```
<div class="post-bottom">
    <div class="post-text-container">
        <?php
            /* translators: %s: Name of current post*/
            $postURL = get_permalink();
            $commentsURL = get_comments_link();
            the_content( sprintf(
                __(  ),
                the_title( '<span class="screen-reader-text">', '</span>', false )
            ) );
            if ( !is_single() ) :
                    echo "<div class=\"read-more\"><a href=\"$postURL\">Continue reading...</a> | <a href=\"$commentsURL\">Full Comments</a></div>";
                endif;
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

What can be the cause of this?

Edit: the only things that I changed when coping stuff to my local server were:

1 - I copied my database to my local phpmyadmin and changed all `http://www.example.com` to `http://localhost/example` in the options table.

2 - I totally removed my .htaccess file (and wordpress generated a new one by it self)

This is how the one on the server looks:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

and this is what I have locally:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /example/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /example/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

3- I enabled "rewrite_modle" on WAMP because it's disabled by default.

Comment: If you put `''` like: `__('')` what happens? (on your local server)

Comment: The warning isn't related to your htaccess file (as far as I know). It's a PHP issue - maybe versions or specific setting in php.ini?

Comment: @OfirBaruch Toda! 
This worked. 
So it's because of differences with the `php.ini`. I don't usually play around with servers so I don't know how to check versions and configure.

Comment: May I write it as an answer and you'll approve it? (I'll also show you the reason for next times ;) )

Comment: @OfirBaruch yalla :D

Comment: Added (Hosafti). Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning is regarding the following part of your code:  `__( )`.

In WP `__` is actually a function for translation purposes.

From a short look [in the manual](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2), we can see that the `__()` function usage is:

```
<?php $translated_text = __( $text, $domain ); ?>
```

And that the `$text` parameter is required.

> $text (string) (required) Text to translate. Default: None $domain
>
> (string) (optional) Domain to retrieve the translated text. Default:
>   'default'

In your code, you don't send any argument to that function and therefore you're getting a legit warning. To be honest, I don't know why there was no argument in the first place. Moreover, also your remote server should show that warning. In case it doesn't - or the code is different or you have `error_reporting(0)` somewhere on the server (php.ini / wp-config.php).

A simple solution would be just to add an empty string as an argument.

Comment: All the files are copied exactly the same - so I guess it's something within the php.ini 

Do you recommend to fix this in the php.ini for future situations like this?

Comment: having a low level or none `error_reporting` would make you blind for possible error or mistakes (like having a blank white page instead of an error that could help you locating the bug). However, since you have a local version, it will be better to leave that setting as it is. You don't want your visitors to see errors. Just remember to test every change in your local environment before uploading to production.

Answer (score 2):

Try putting this in your wp-config.php, this doesn't solve the issue but this is basically the difference between your server and your local.

```
error_reporting(0);
```

It's a warning and you can suppress it, its not an error.

To solve the issue, you will need to pass a string to`__()` function because it expects a string to be passed. Read more here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/_2

Comment: Won't you prefer solving the problem that causing the warning rather than ignoring it?

Comment: The question is "Why do I get an error message on local but not server", so I am giving him a reason as to why that is the case. Yes, its better to solve the issue, but you can choose to ignore it.

Comment: I prefer solving this. 
I think it's because of the .htaccess file I think
I'm editing my post and adding what I have in my .htaccess file just in case